# Problema na função send_email do Django

Tags: html, python, django, formulário, email

Boa tarde!

tenho o seguinte código no views.py:

```
def email(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            form.email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            form.subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
            form.message = request.POST.get('message', '')
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['email']
            cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']
            recipients = ['unionjunior1@gmail.com']

            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(email)
            send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients, fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
        else:
            form.errors
else:
        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'main.html', {'form': form})
```

e no Settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'unionjunior1@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
```

A função está funcionando e eu recebo o e-mail conforme setado. **O problema** é que o email está sendo enviado para o mesmo local que ele é recebido (*to_email* e *from_email* estão sendo iguais). A variável *sender* preenche o parâmetro *to_email* da função *send_email*, mas por alguma razão estou enviando e recebendo para o mesmo email.
Eu penso que não faz muito sentido o usuário conseguir enviar um e-mail do seu próprio endereço para outro, através de um formulário de um site sem autenticação mas de qualquer forma, também não sei como manipular este parâmetro *to_email* para saber quem enviou aquela mensagem para o e-mail destinatário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que você está tentando fazer com que o usuário que preencheu o formulário envie um e-mail para você. Mas no caso as coisas não vão funcionar bem assim. Pelo menos, até hoje, quando precisei de fazer um formulário onde o cliente enviasse um e-mail para mim, sempre coloco o e-mail que o mesmo preencheu no formulário no corpo da mensagem recebida através da aplicação.

Vale lembrar que nem todas as plataformas/servidores de e-mail aceitam você definir um remetente diferente daquele que é utilizado na autenticação SMTP (pelo menos, todas vezes que tentei isso, nunca deu certo).

Talvez seja apenas uma questão de regra de negócio. Eu , no seu caso, apenas criaria uma mensagem padrão, identificando de qual aplicação é, e enviaria a mensagem normalmente, mesmo sendo o destinatário e o remetente a mesma pessoa, e colocaria no corpo do e-mail o valor preenchido pelo usuário lá no formulário.

Por exemplo:

```
FROM: email@me.com
TO:   email@me.com

Subject: Mensagem recebido a aplicação XXX - Assunto

BODY: O usuário de nome {{ nome }} envio a seguinte mensagem através do formulário a aplicação XXX.   

 bla bla bla bla bla

 Para responder esse usuário, utilize o e-mail {{ email_que_foi_preenchido_no_formulario }}
```

**Acréscimo**: Talvez você também queira também usar o formulário para responder as mensagens para o usuário, de forma que a comunicação (resposta de e-mails) fiquem empilhadas. Uma ideia boa é continuar enviando o e-mail "pra si mesmo", porém adicionando o e-mail do usuário do formulário como CC (Com cópia)

Comment: Muito obrigado! clareou bastante! Problema resolvido :)